# Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've added the code as below and got the below exception.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@RESDEV:1521:resdev" /> 
    <property name="user" value="resources"/> 
    <property name="password" value="dev_resorces"/> 
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```

Stacktrace:

```
18:26:11,508 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@58c58fb3: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,viewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,dataSource,ressessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,accessDAO,loginService,accessService]; root of factory hierarchy
18:26:11,515 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource from [Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource from [Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource from [Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource from [Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1261) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1330) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:75) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:109) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:88) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource from [Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257) [spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 34 more
```

This is my `spring_config.xml` file which has both spring and hibernate configuration details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lv.automation.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
    <mvc:resources location="/style/style.css" mapping="/style/**" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />

    <bean id="ressessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jboss/OracleDS/RESGlobaldata</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> -->

                 <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@RESDEV:1521:resdev</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">resources</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">dev_resorces</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">resources</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> 
                    <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.lv.automation.vo.Printer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="ressessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDAO" class="com.lv.automation.dao.impl.AccessDAOImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="ressessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="loginService" class="com.lv.automation.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="accessService" class="com.lv.automation.service.impl.AccessServiceImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

This is the error from log which is received while adding the war:

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:564) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) [spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) [spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149) [spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119) [spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81) [spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113) [hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) [hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) [hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) [hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860) [spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779) [spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211) [spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace of the error to your question.

Comment: I Have added.Please chcke it

Comment: cam you specify on which server your are deploying the application. Copy paste also your spring config files.

Comment: Iam deploying it in JBOSS 7 server. please find my config files attached.

Comment: please edit your question properly, config files are missing and `THis is the error from log which is received while adding the war` line is repeated many times

Comment: please find my config files attached

Comment: @Anu, please post your questions properly in SO, why you want to use capital letters and repeated statements every where.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a datasource in Spring then you must provide all the DB connection parameters like URL, user, password etc.

[Check this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html) for reference

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
        <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/> 
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/> 
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
    </bean>
```

As you need to provide connection details to datasource, you can remove these settings for hibernate, means remove these lines:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@RESDEV:1521:resdev</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.connection.username">resources</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.connection.password">dev_resorces</prop>
```

**Update:**

I just gave you a reference on how to declare the datasource. The error clearly says `Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource]`, if you want to use this datasource class then download the required jar and place it in classpath.

Also you can refer to this link on how various configurations looks like with Spring and hibernate - http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@RESDEV:1521:resdev" /> 
        <property name="user" value="resources"/> 
        <property name="password" value="dev_resorces"/> 
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
    </bean>.i HAVE ADDED LIKE THIS AND GETTING ERROR

Comment: @Anu, what is that error, update your question with its stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Download oracle driver `ojdbcx.jar` vers x is the java version (for example ojdbc6.jar for java 6) and either add it to your EAR file or just drop it in your Jboss deploy folder.

By the way, you may prefer to define a datasource with a pool managed by jboss instead of defining connection pool in your application. Such stuff should be managed by the application server. You will access it through JNDI when you need it. You will find tons of tutorial on the net about it (ask google).

Comment: Hi, can you tell me, how to modify the servlet.xml file for using pool manger by JBOSS, i have placed my properties file inside the server and help me with syntax to point to JNDI name from servlet.xml file.